# Can generator function execution continue after an error is thrown in this pattern?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, redux-saga, yield

[These docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw) make me think the answer could potentially be yes - but I always thought no and my tests show the same.

The reason for my question is that a generator function seems to have done exactly this in my project exactly once, and I cannot recreate it, nor can I find any error in my code - so I started thinking the error is in my assumptions.

```js
function* someMethod(i) {
  try {
    yield i;
    throw new Error('error text');
    yield call(anotherMethod); // << This should never be executed, right?
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

Comment: Once it makes it to the `catch` clause the function is going to exit

Answer (score 2):

Your "pattern" is incomplete, so we can't tell what else is going on. Yes, the line marked by the comment, right after the `throw` statement, will never be executed. But the line inside the `catch` block, and the lines after it, will execute - and they can contain more `yield` expressions, which will suspend the execution and allow it to be resumed later:

```js
function* someMethod(i) {
  try {
    yield 'start it up';
    yield 'This is not executed'; // if the previous line throws
  } catch (err) {
    yield 'but this is';
  }
  yield 'and so is this';
}
const gen = someMethod();
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.throw());
console.log(gen.next());
console.log(gen.next());
```

This can be used to create generators that will never end and can always be continued, no matter what you `.throw()` at them:

```
function* ignoreErrors() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      yield;
    } catch(e) {}
  }
}
```

We can even build generators on which you can invoke `.return()` and they won't stop:

```
function* forever() {
  try {
    yield;
  } finally {
    return yield* forever();
  }
}
```

or without relying on tail recursion (which is neither specified nor implemented for this anyway), but even more horrible code:

```
function* forever() {
  run: while (true) {
    try {
      yield;
    } finally {
      continue run;
    }
  }
}
```